# What is the best way to write a query to show the list of people going to a specified event?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not used to SQL tables with a column for field name and one for fieldValue, so I would like to know the best query to solve my problem.

My table has a column for ID, FieldName, and FieldValue:

```
ID FieldName FieldValue
1  FName     John
2  LName     Smith
3  Email     JSmith@gmail.com
4  event_0   Movies
5  event_1   Dinner
6  FName     Mike
7  LName     Jones
...
```

I need to show all attendees for 'Movies' and show a count for all going to the movies. Also, another issue that I am running into is that sometimes someone who fills out the form will only have event_0, and sometimes they will have event_0, event_1, event_2.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample data and what you have tried so far? Also, what platform are you talking about (e.g. mysql, postgresql, something else)?
Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm doing it in SQL Server Management just sql code. And I don't even really know where to start because I'm unsure the best way to find event within a column

Comment: so if you have another people, FName is bob, and have event_0 is Movies, how do you know this Movies is for Bob not for John?

Comment: Do you think that would cause issue? That just means they are signing up for the same event.

Comment: Where is Mike Jones attending? How'd we know that?

Comment: I mean its all random, if you assume Movies that's fine as an example

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a sample result of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Some only have Movies, some only have Dinner, and some have both

Comment: There's no 'entity' here; only an 'attribute' and a 'value'. Perhaps an entity can be inferred from the id and the subsequent occurrence of an attribute, but this seems unnecessarily complicated. Is there any attribute that is common to all attendees

Comment: I agree Strawberry, but sadly its not my job to change the structure, just make the queries

Comment: I think this is an occasion where you are going to need a cursor or 2.

Comment: You mentioned SQL Server Management  (studio?)- which makes me think this is a sqlserver question.

Comment: Are the various records always ordered the same way? I mean, all 'event' records belong to the person corresponding to the highest id, lower than the id of the event itself?

Answer (score 0):

your table looks like a table I had to deal with in the past, the client had a table with  columns as records instead of rows in order to customize the fields in a form ( a column for each field name and a column for its values).

The way I dealt with that was :
- making a pivot table using CASE WHEN for each row ...

I will explain you how to with some code in a couple of hours

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I'll look forward to it!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might solve your first query where you can check how many people are going for movies as well as other events also.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), FieldValue
FROM table_name
GROUP BY FieldValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to think about... a solution exclusively for versions of MySQL prior to 8.0.

This is absolutely dependent on contact details consistently preceding events.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,attribute VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'FName','John'),
(2,'LName','Smith'),
(3,'Email','JSmith@gmail.com'),
(4,'event_0','Movies'),
(5,'event_1','Dinner'),
(6,'FName','Mike'),
(7,'LName','Jones');

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'fname' THEN value END) fname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'lname' THEN value END) lname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'email' THEN value END) email
  FROM 
     ( SELECT CASE WHEN attribute = 'fname' THEN @entity := @entity+1 ELSE @entity:=@entity END entity
            , attribute
            , value 
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @entity := 0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY entity
HAVING MAX(attribute LIKE 'event_%' AND value = 'Movies') = 1;

+-------+-------+--------------+
| fname | lname | email        |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| John  | Smith | JSmith@gmail |
+-------+-------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is broken.  You don't have a simple way to determine which rows are assigned to the same "person" or "entity".  You should have another column.  Remember:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so the ordering of rows is not a valid way to identify something.

If you want a count of people going to movies, how about this:

```
select count(*)
from t
where fieldname in ('event_0', 'event_1', 'event_2') and
      fieldvalue = 'Movies';
```

This gets the number of rows with movies, which seems pretty close to what you want.